# Internationalization does not work in pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-i18n

I have deployed my Django website to PythonAnywhere last week and in the meantime, I made some changes to texts on the website. Now, I am trying to translate these pieces of text using the internationalization package in PythonAnywhere, but somehow it does not work.

When I run `python manage.py makemessages -l en`, my `django.po` file is updated and I am able to add the translations, but once I run `python manage.py compilemessages -l en`, the English translations do not show up on the website.

The first day, I did get the translations to work, but now they don't anymore. What could be the cause of this? And could anybody help me find a way to solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: _"The first day, I did get the translations to work, but now they don't anymore."_ It seems then that your changes broke it. Then you have a good reference point. Either start removing small bits until your back where you started, or start from the first day and copy in your changes until you notice the break. Remember to save a copy of your current file so you don't lose the changes you've made.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I only made small changes to the text (changing simple words and sentences). Could these changes have been the cause?

Comment: Yeah, you may have made the translations fuzzy and they might then not show up. You'd need to check through the `.po` file and make sure they're not showing as `fuzzy`.

Comment: They are actually not fuzzy. For instance one of the pieces of text that does not get translated is in the `po` file as follows: `#: templates/QUIZ/GForm.html:23
msgid ""
"De survey is beschikbaar in verschillende talen. Rechstboven in het venster "
"kunt u de taal selecteren."
msgstr ""
"The survey is available in different languages. In the upper right corner of "
"the window below you can select the language." `

Comment: Does it work in your dev environnement ?

Comment: I found the issue! Thank you.

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question if you want. It could helps others that  will face the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Apparantely I was just being stupid, as I used some commands from my dev environment in PythonAnywhere...
What solved my issues:

- Do not run python manage.py runserver in PythonAnywhere, as it will stop your site from updating these kinds of things.
- Keep an eye on fuzzy translations.

Comment: Nice! You can also mark your answer as accepted so the question will be marked as solved